# why is the BERT NSP task useful for sentence classification tasks?

Tags: bert

BERT pre-trains the special `[CLS]` token on the NSP task - for every pair `A-B` predicting whether sentence B follows sentence A in the corpus or not.
When fine-tuning BERT for sentence classification (e.g. spam or not), it is recommended to use a degenerate pair `A-null` and use the `[CLS]` token output for our task.

How is that making sense? in the pre-training stage, BERT never saw such pairs, how come it will eat them just fine and "know" that instead of extracting the relation between A and B it is to extract the meaning of sentence A as there is no sentence B?

Is there another practice of fine-tuning the model with `A-spam` and `A-notspam` for every sentence A, and seeing which pair gets the better NSP score? or is that totally equivalent to fine tuning with `A-null`?

related to [Bert-Transformer : Why Bert transformer uses [CLS] token for classification instead of average over all tokens?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/77044/bert-transformer-why-bert-transformer-uses-cls-token-for-classification-inst)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motivation is that the `[CLS]` embedding should contain "a summary" of both sentences to be able to decide if they follow each other or not.

However, in follow-up papers such as [RoBERTa](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.11692) or [XLNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08237), only the masked LM objective is used and they reach better results than the original BERT.

Here is the table with with results from the [RoBERTa paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.11692.pdf) (Table 2 on page 5) that specifically measures the effect of the next-sentence-prediction (NSP) loss.NS

[image]

Comment: also, craffel@ the author of T5 tried a variant of NSP (prefix lm) and showed its worse then masked lm https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/5388#issuecomment-652142076